# Objects off artboard in inDesign very dark / almosted greyed out

Tags: adobe-indesign, artboard

Ive got an inDesign document with my main artboards, around the artboards are all the images / text etc that i haven't used / included. Normally these items off the artboard are completely legible, but for some reason the images seem greyed out and if i place text in the side areas it dosnt show up at all unless its bounding text box is selected.

Any idea why this is / how to resolve it ? I guess it must have been triggered by a particular setting being turned on, ive browsed through the view tool bar but couldnt see anything that would seem to effect it.

This is a screenshot of how the off artboard images currently looks

[image: artboard screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overprint Preview is on. CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+Y to turn it off or it's the first item in the View toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was **Proof Colors**. You can turn it off with `CTRL` + `Y`